# Miro does not convert the entire file when converting to webm

Tags: video

I am trying to convert files from .mov to .webm with Miro on a Mac for publishing to the web with HTML5. The conversions go fine for about 75% of the file but then Miro does not convert the rest of the file. I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue and what they did to get around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried using Miro as well to transcode H.264 MP4 into VP-8 WebM so that Firefox would play using HTML5 rather than a Flash fallback.

- But at least when the mp4 source was exported from Premiere then the Miro conversion did not work properly
- it finished in my case, but the webm file would always start to play from the last second of the video for some reason (try it with VLC, for instance).

#### FireFogg Worked

My solution was to use FireFogg, which can encode into webm as well
http://firefogg.org/

Instructions here, just choose webmsd or webhd instead of ogg: [Video - Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#firefogg)

Comment: Thanks! I'll bookmark this and try it next time I need to do a conversion. :)